# Regex find all matches EXCEPT those surrounded by characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regular expression to find all of the instances of {word} in my string.  In the following string, this (correctly) matches {eeid} and {catalog}:

Expression
`{([^:]*?)}`

String being searched
`{?:participants::lookup(.,{eeid},{catalog})}`

Now - I need to "escape" one of those values, so it is NOT matched/replaced.    I'm trying to use double square brackets to do so:

`{?:participants::lookup(.,{eeid},[[{catalog}]])}`

How can I adjust my regular expression so it ignores {catalog} (enclosed in [[ ]]) but finds {eeid}?

Comment: Try: `(?<!\[\[(?:(?!\[\[|]]).)*){([^{}]*)}(?!(?:(?!\[\[|]]).)*]])` assuming `[[` and `]]` are not always adjacent to `{...}`

Comment: They ARE always adjacent.   I want to preserve (Not match) anything like [[{...}]]

Comment: In that case use `(?<!\[\[){([^{}]*)}(?!]])`

Comment: That works...  I actually had to add another bit back to the expression, the [^:] (I also don't want to match where there is a colon :)   ```(?<!\[\[){([^:{}]*)}(?!]])``` is what I end up with.  Seems to work!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?<!\[\[)\{([^:{}]*)}(?!]])
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5C%5B%5C%5B%29%5C%7B%28%5B%5E%3A%7B%7D%5D*%29%7D%28%3F!%5D%5D%29&i=%7B%3F%3Aparticipants%3A%3Alookup%28.%2C%7Beeid%7D%2C%7Bcatalog%7D%29%7D%0D%0A%7B%3F%3Aparticipants%3A%3Alookup%28.%2C%7Beeid%7D%2C%5B%5B%7Bcatalog%7D%5D%5D%29%7D).

**Details**

- `(?<!\[\[)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `[[` immediately to the left of the current location
- `\{` - a `{` char
- `([^:{}]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `:`, `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}` char
- `(?!]])` - a  negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `]]` immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/OrBH6G):

```cs
var s = "{?:participants::lookup(.,{eeid},[[{catalog}]])}";
var rx = @"(?<!\[\[)\{([^:{}]*)}(?!]])";
var res = Regex.Matches(s, rx).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
foreach (var t in res)
    Console.WriteLine(t);

// => eeid
```

Comment: Good explanation and example - marking as the answer, even though it was already answered by @anubhava in comments on the original question.